# Regex match if it has a word and other word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches if the string has a word, "worker", and doesn't have another, "TextNotification".

I have an example here with what I've been working: http://rubular.com/r/sjYWePWk0s

In this case, out of the four lines, I should only get matched the first one.

Comment: Please include your regex and test cases in the question; don't make it mandatory to follow an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Use this regex with lookahead before actual match:

```
^(?!.*TextNotification).*worker.*$
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/sxlKjoMmL8)

Answer (score 0):

Do this as two separate tests.

1. Test for `worker`.  If that test succeeds, then
2. Test for `TextNotification`.  If that test fails, then
3. You have your data.

Trying to cram everything into one single regular expression is often

1. Prone to errors.
2. Unreadable.